# ATA Trusted commands in Linux

Tags: linux, security, storage, ata

Colleagues,

I'm implementing support for ATA trusted commands

```
0x5C, TRUSTED RECEIVE, 
0x5D, TRUSTED RECEIVE DMA, 
0x5E, TRUSTED SEND
0x5F, TRUSTED SEND DMA,
```

for Linux (two hosts, Fedora 12 and 14) to support self-encrypting drives. I took a code from this page http://www.jukie.net/bart/blog/ata-via-scsi as the base code. For trusted receive (on this layer it is identical to IDENTIFY, 0xEC):

```
sg_io.interface_id    = 'S';
sg_io.cmdp            = cdb;
sg_io.cmd_len         = sizeof(cdb);
sg_io.dxferp          = data_in_buffer;
sg_io.dxfer_len       = data_in_length;         // multiple of 512
sg_io.dxfer_direction = SG_DXFER_FROM_DEV;
sg_io.sbp             = sense;
sg_io.mx_sb_len       = sizeof(sense);
sg_io.timeout         = 5000;                   // 5 seconds


cdb[0] = 0x85;           // pass-through ATA16 command (no translation)
cdb[1] = (4 << 1);       // data-in
cdb[2] = 0x2e;           // data-in
cdb[4] = feature_id;     // ATA feature ID
cdb[6] = 1;              // number of sectors
cdb[7] = lba_low >> 8;
cdb[8] = lba_low;
cdb[9] = lba_mid >> 8;
cdb[10] = lba_mid;
cdb[11] = lba_high >> 8;
cdb[12] = lba_high;
cdb[14] = 0x5C;           // TRUSTED RECEIVE

rc = ioctl (fd, SG_IO, &sg_io);
```

It works perfectly for Identify and all other commands, but not for trusted commands. When I connect protocol analyzer, I see that these commands are not sent to SATA bus. The adaptor is capable to send them, because they are coming OK under Windows (not my code, but I think using ATA_PASS_THROUGH). And yes, I'm running this code as root.

Please help to resolve this mystery :)

Comment: what are lba_low, lba_mid, and lba_high.. How can I find information about setting these variables?

Answer (score 5):

See [/usr/src/linux/drivers/ata/libata-scsi.c](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=drivers/ata/libata-scsi.c;hb=HEAD):

```
/*
 * Filter TPM commands by default. These provide an
 * essentially uncontrolled encrypted "back door" between
 * applications and the disk. Set libata.allow_tpm=1 if you
 * have a real reason for wanting to use them. This ensures
 * that installed software cannot easily mess stuff up without
 * user intent. DVR type users will probably ship with this enabled
 * for movie content management.
 *
 * Note that for ATA8 we can issue a DCS change and DCS freeze lock
 * for this and should do in future but that it is not sufficient as
 * DCS is an optional feature set. Thus we also do the software filter
 * so that we comply with the TC consortium stated goal that the user
 * can turn off TC features of their system.
 */
if (tf->command >= 0x5C && tf->command <= 0x5F && !libata_allow_tpm)
        goto invalid_fld;
```

Comment: It seems like "modprobe libata allow_tpm=1" doesn't work on my Fedora 14.

Comment: @Dmitry: It doesn't work if `libata` is already loaded.  You'll have to boot with `libata.allow_tpm=1` on the kernel command line or with `options libata allow_tpm=1` in `/etc/modprobe.conf` or `/etc/modprobe.d/*.conf`, depending on how the system is set up.

Comment: For those who might be interested in a tool to configure TCG drives: https://sourceforge.net/projects/tcgparm/

Comment: What are the lba_low, lba_mid and lba_high variables? HOw to set their values?

Comment: Can anyone expand the TPM acronym used here?

Comment: @Wilbur Trusted Platform Module (TPM)

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel no, I don't think that's it.  That's why I asked.  This is ATA, not TCG Trusted Platform.

Comment: See ATA specs: Trusted Security Protocol field 01h-06h: Defined by TCG

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel if that's the case, it would be TCG, no TPM.  What TPM relevant information could POSSIBLY be put in a field in an ATA command?

Comment: Found it: libata_allow_tpm is a flag that serves effectively to indiscriminately  block ATA TRUSTED SEND/RECV commands (opcodes 0x5C-0x5F).  See [this commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/ata/libata-scsi.c?id=ae8d4ee7ff429136c8b482c3b38ed994c021d3fc).  If the 'tpm' here really was meant as Trusted Platform Module, I think it represents a gross misunderstanding of terminology by the kernel developer.