# ATA Trusted commands-How to set libata allow_tpm

Tags: linux, security, ata

I want to send trusted send/trusted receive to my hard drive. I found this page:
[ATA Trusted commands in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703957/ata-trusted-commands-in-linux).
(Thanks you ephemient and Dmitry Obukhov).

For now, my trouble is how to set libata allow_tpm = 1.
I'm using Ubuntu 13.10. My code is same as Dmitry Obukhov (It works perfectly for Identify and all other commands, but not for trusted commands.)

After looking in another side, these are what I did:

```
- In BIOS, set AHCI mode.
```

In terminal:

```
- sudo dmesg -c:

   [    0.157207] SCSI subsystem initialized.

   [    0.157209] ACPI: bus type ATA registered.

   [    0.157236] libata version 3.00 loaded.

   [    0.878999] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 6 ports 6
   Gbps 0x3 impl SATA mode.

   [    0.887125] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf7c16000 port
   0xf7c16100 irq 41.

   [    0.887127] ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf7c16000 port
   0xf7c16180 irq 41.

   [    1.205449] ata2: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl
   300).

   [    1.205477] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl
   300).

   [    1.206127] ata2.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully
   accessible.

   [    1.206131] ata2.00: ATA-8: ST500LT025-1A5142, 0001SDM7, max
   UDMA/133.

   [    1.206133] ata2.00: 976773168 sectors, multi 1: LBA48 NCQ (depth
   31/32).

   [    1.206159] ata1.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully
   accessible.

   [    1.206163] ata1.00: ATA-8: ST500LT025-1A5142, 0001SDM7, max
   UDMA/133.

   [    1.206165] ata1.00: 976773168 sectors, multi 1: LBA48 NCQ (depth
   31/32).



- systool -a -v -m libata

  Module = "libata"

  Attributes:
    uevent              = <store method only>
    version             = "3.00"

  Parameters:
    acpi_gtf_filter     = "7"
    allow_tpm           = "0"
    ata_probe_timeout   = "0"
    atapi_an            = "0"
    atapi_dmadir        = "0"
    atapi_enabled       = "1"
    atapi_passthru16    = "1"
    dma                 = "7"
    fua                 = "0"
    ignore_hpa          = "0"
    noacpi              = "0"
    zpodd_poweroff_delay= "30"

- sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf.
  Add this line: options libata allow_tpm=1

- sudo nano /boot/grub/menu.lst.
  Add this line: combined_mode=libata

- sudo update-initramfs -u&& sudo update-grub2
```

After reboot, I run `systool -a -v -m libata` again, nothing change with `allow_tpm`. What should I do to change `allow_tpm`?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to change `allow_tpm` permanently tell `grub` doing so by adding `libata.allow_tpm=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`. For example:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.allow_tpm=1"
```

Afterwards run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this for CentOs 7: Uefi Boot

Add kernel flag: `libata.allow_tpm=1`

I tried this for CentOs 7 : Uefi Boot & it worked like charm:

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub`
2. Add `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.allow_tpm=1"`
3. Save it
4. Run command: `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg` 
   or for non-uefi OS `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`
5. `systemctl reboot`
6. `cat /proc/cmdline` you see as below

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.X86_64 root=/dev/mapper/centos-root ro crashkernel=autord.lvm.lv=centos/root rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap rhgb quite splash libata.allow_tpm=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just success in changing value of allow_tpm, so ATA Trusted commands work now.

```
- cd /sys/module/libata/parameters
- sudo chmod 644 allow_tpm
- sudo nano allow_tpm
  Delete number 0 and write number 1. Save file.
```

Maybe this is not a exactly way because value in file allow_tpm is reset 0 every time I reboot computer.

Comment: I got an error trying to modify and save this file (yes, with root privilege). If this fails, try the /etc/default/grub method.

Comment: If you don't use GRUB, look for the relevant file and edit it - more boot loader configurations here : https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Kernel_parameters#systemd-boot